# jquery find by input name not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which works fine in Chrome IE and Safari, but I cant get it to work with Firefox. I am getting all the values from multiple checkboxes from the `name="grouptype[]"` values. Can anyone help me with a solution that will work with firefox and the other browsers?

**JQUERY**

```
$("form.loginForm").submit(function () {
  event.preventDefault();   
  var grouptype = $(this).find('input[name="grouptype[]"]');
  grouptype.each(function (i) {
    console.log($(this).val() + ' is checked: ' + $(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="loginForm" action="../includes/editremoveuser.php">
    <label><input class="grouptype" id="grouptype1" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$row1['ID']?>" /><?=$row1['title']?></label>
    <label><input class="grouptype" id="grouptype2" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$row1['ID']?>" /><?=$row1['title']?></label>
    <label><input class="grouptype" id="grouptype3" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$row1['ID']?>" /><?=$row1['title']?></label>
    <label><input class="grouptype" id="grouptype4" name="grouptype[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$row1['ID']?>" /><?=$row1['title']?></label>
</form>
```

Comment: What does the html structure look like? Also, what is `this` in the statement `$(this).find('input[name="grouptype[]"]');`?

Comment: Can you upload your code to a JSfiddle? Hard to tell what is going on with this code snippet

Comment: It should be `.submit(function(event) {`. Also, this isn't the cause of the issue, but your checkboxes should either not have IDs or have unique IDs. ID values in HTML should be unique for the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event` is not global in firefox like it is in most other browsers. Add it as an input for your event handler and it should resolve the issue:

```
$("form.loginForm").submit(function (event) {
    // Same code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Compatible firefox
    $("form.loginForm").submit(function (event) {
        event = event || window.event;
    });

Comment: can you add some explanation?